# PHP GD imagettftext measurements

Tags: php, text, gd

I'm trying to write a script that generates a PNG image from the text, size and the font it gets in the $_GET arguments, but I can't figure out how to make size of the image fit exactly to the text. I'm already using imagettfbox:

```
$widthPx = abs($ttfBox[2] - $ttfBox[0]);
$heightPx = abs($ttfBox[1] - $ttfBox[7]);
```

which probably gives me the correct measurements but when I draw my text, it gets a little bit out of bounds. For example if I try to draw an "a" using arial.ttf its at least 5 pixels out of bounds. Is there a way to draw a text of any font exactly fitting to the image without testing out?

```
$text = $_GET["text"];

$cmToPixel = 15.0;

$sizeCm = floatval($_GET["sizeCm"]);
$sizePx = $cmToPixel * $sizeCm;
$fontFile = "fonts/".pathinfo($_GET["font"])["filename"].".".pathinfo($_GET["font"])["extension"];

if(!file_exists($fontFile)){
    die;
}
$ttfBox = imagettfbbox($sizePx, 0, $fontFile, $text);

$widthPx = abs($ttfBox[2] - $ttfBox[0]);
$heightPx = abs($ttfBox[1] - $ttfBox[7]);

$image = ImageCreate($widthPx, $heightPx);

$x = $ttfBox[0] + (imagesx($image)-$ttfBox[4] )/ 2 - 0;
$y = $ttfBox[1] + (imagesy($image) / 2) - ($ttfBox[5] / 2) - 5;

ImageRectangle($image,0,0,imagesx($image),imagesy($image), ImageColorAllocate($image,255,255,255));
imagettftext($image, $sizePx,0,$x,$y, ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0), $fontFile, $text);

header("Content-Type: image/png");
ImagePng($image);
ImageDestroy($image);
```

Comment: Have you had a look at the examples provided with the manual? They may help: [imagettfbbox — Give the bounding box of a text using TrueType fonts](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php)

Comment: I already had a look at all the examples, it seems that I have to trim the image by testing pixel colors, because the text output is just too inaccurate. Every text has a different offset when I draw it so it's always out of bounds.

Comment: Would it be possible to post the code that you use so we can experiment with it?

Comment: I added the code, I tried different things for the x and y coordinates of the text, doesn't quite make a difference. Probably better to try a different approach like trimming the image by pixel colors.

Comment: The issue is that GD doesn't use the 'font metrics' which give values and offsets from the 'baseline' of characters. Imagack does use these values so is more accurate. Basically, in GD, you end up with some 'fudge' factors that are 'font family' dependent. Getting 'imagick' working on 'windows' is 'less than fun' and i haven't managed it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations from the bounding box are off. This works:

```
<?php
/*-
 * $MirOS: www/mk/ttf2png,v 1.8 2016/11/02 16:16:26 tg Exp $
 *-
 * Copyright (c) 2009, 2016
 *  mirabilos <m@mirbsd.org>
 *
 * Provided that these terms and disclaimer and all copyright notices
 * are retained or reproduced in an accompanying document, permission
 * is granted to deal in this work without restriction, including un-
 * limited rights to use, publicly perform, distribute, sell, modify,
 * merge, give away, or sublicence.
 *
 * This work is provided "AS IS" and WITHOUT WARRANTY of any kind, to
 * the utmost extent permitted by applicable law, neither express nor
 * implied; without malicious intent or gross negligence. In no event
 * may a licensor, author or contributor be held liable for indirect,
 * direct, other damage, loss, or other issues arising in any way out
 * of dealing in the work, even if advised of the possibility of such
 * damage or existence of a defect, except proven that it results out
 * of said person's immediate fault when using the work as intended.
 *-
 * Syntax:
 *  php ttf2png [text [size [/path/to/font.ttf]]] >out.png
 */

if (!function_exists('gd_info'))
    die("Install php5-gd first.");
$gd = gd_info();
if ($gd["FreeType Support"] == false)
    die("Compile php5-gd with FreeType 2 support.");


$font = "/usr/src/www/files/FNT/GenI102.ttf";
$fontsize = 30;
$text = "EINVAL";

if (isset($argv[1]))
    $text = $argv[1];
if (isset($argv[2]))
    $fontsize = $argv[2];
if (isset($argv[3]))
    $font = $argv[3];


// Get bounding box
$bbox = imageftbbox($fontsize, 0, $font, $text);
// Transform coordinates into width+height and position
$ascender = abs($bbox[7]);
$descender = abs($bbox[1]);
$size_w = abs($bbox[0]) + abs($bbox[2]);
$size_h = $ascender + $descender;
$x = -$bbox[0];
$y = $ascender;

// Create image
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($size_w, $size_h);
// Allocate colours
$bgcol = imagecolorallocate($im, 0x24, 0x24, 0x24);
$fgcol = imagecolorallocate($im, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF);

// Fill image with background colour
imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, $size_w - 1, $size_h - 1, $bgcol);
// Render text into image
imagefttext($im, $fontsize, 0, $x, $y, $fgcol, $font, $text);

// Convert true colour image (needed for above) to palette image
imagetruecolortopalette($im, FALSE, 256);

// Output created image
imagepng($im, NULL, 9);

exit(0);
```

If you write multiple strings on the same line and need to calculate the total height and offset of the line, it’s the maximum of all ascenders plus the maximum of all descenders, and `$y` for *all* `imagefttext` calls for that line is similarily the maximum of all ascenders.

Comment: @MarcielFonseca that’s a PNG, save it to a file or pipe it through `xloadimage stdin` or some other suitable image viewer. It’s common for Unix tools to dump the result to stdout, in order to be able to be used as a filter through pipes.